# CTRL+V sometimes adds the number 8 to pasted text or just pastes the number 8

Tags: windows-10, copy-paste

In my Windows 10 laptop, I have this weird intermittent behavior while pasting text using CTRL+V.

It sometimes adds the number `8` to the pasted text or just pastes the number `8`.

For e.g. if I copy/cut the text *`my_copied_text`* and press CTRL+V, I get *`8my_copied_text`* or just *`8`*.

I am out of my wits, where does the number 8 come from and why number 8?

Right Click + Paste with mouse works fine.

Comment: Maybe a keyboard issue.  Does it happen if you right-click and choose Copy/Paste?

Comment: @squillman No issues with right click paste. It pastes the right text.

Comment: So Ctrl-V pastes the number 8 while right-click/Paste does not with the same clipboard entry? Maybe try cleaning your keyboard out (compressed air).

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?